# numpy curve_fitting fail to run a specific set

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a set of numbers which cause error when I try to do a curve fitting to them. I'm quite certain I managed to do this before with the same numbers (I'm certain I did with other data sets). What is causing this error then?

The `X`, `Y`, `Err` values are (by order of appearance)

```
[0.0, 0.6931471805599453, 1.3862943611198906]
[-5.354761064902713, -6.190455611580044, -6.558604540577015]
[0.0014079400762288246, 0.0006083544693643583, 0.0002989970199491765]
```

and `kappa` is equal to 8

This is the function I try to fit (largely a + 2*x)

```
 out = []
    for x in X:
        y = log(kappa)
        y += 4*log(pi)
        y += 2*x 
        y -= 2*log(2)
        out.append(-y)
    return np.array(out)
```

this is how I call `curve_fit`

```
 popt,pcov = curve_fit(fitFunc1,self.X[0:3],self.Y[0:3],sigma=self.Err[0:3],p0=kappa)
```

and this is the error I get

```
popt,pcov = curve_fit(fitFunc1,self.X[0:3],self.Y[0:3],sigma=self.Err[0:3],p0=kappa)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 506, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 355, in leastsq
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
minpack.error: Error occurred while calling the Python function named _weighted_general_function
```

---

*edit 1*

Added `kappa` value (8)

---

*edit 2*

Here is a minimal working example of this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from math import log,pi
X = [0.0, 0.6931471805599453, 1.3862943611198906]
Y = [-5.354761064902713, -6.190455611580044, -6.558604540577015]
Err = [0.0014079400762288246, 0.0006083544693643583, 0.0002989970199491765]
kappa = 8

def func(X,kappa):
    out = []
    for x in X:
        y = log(kappa)
        y += 4*log(pi)
        y += 2*x 
        y -= 2*log(2)
        out.append(-y)
    return np.array(out)


popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,X,Y,sigma=Err,p0=kappa)
```

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code!

Comment: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2008-March/015724.html mind you where is kappa defined?

Comment: @MrE apart from ``kappa`` anything else I missed?

Comment: Ideally post a minimum working example. i.e. code that we can run by copy and pasting in order to reproduce and then fix the problem.

Comment: Is from `out = []` the `fitFunc1`? Is the whitespace also wrong in the function?

Comment: @MrE I just uploaded one.

Comment: @doctorlove no, the white space error is related to the copy-paste + align stuff to appear as code.

Comment: The error is caused by `kappa` being negative after a few calls. The value `kappa = 8` is used for the initial guess only. Let me just make sure I understand. In your setup, your function is `y = 2*log(2) - 2*x - 4 * log(pi) - log(kappa)` and you're trying to fit the parameter `kappa`? Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MrE Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your input arrays to numpy arrays. This allows you to use broadcasting in your `func`. In addition, you should check if `kappa<=0` and return a bad fit value to prevent from evaluating outside the domain you are probably interested in:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
X = np.array([0.0, 0.6931471805599453, 1.3862943611198906])
Y = np.array([-5.354761064902713, -6.190455611580044, -6.558604540577015])
Err = np.array([0.0014079400762288246, 0.0006083544693643583, 0.0002989970199491765])
kappa = 8.0

def func(X,kappa):
    if kappa <=0: return np.inf
    return -(np.log(kappa) + 4*np.log(np.pi) + 2*X - 2*np.log(2))

popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,X,Y,sigma=Err,p0=kappa)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a chance that the way that ``kappa`` is altered between iterations was changed between python2.7 and python3?

Comment: @Yotam I doubt that the internals of `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` broke backwards comparability when they ported to python 3. The doc's make no mention of this either: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html